# Collection of all norms such that a Space is Complete

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

We know that the space of real-valued continuous functions over a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (call is $X$) is complete with respect to the supremum norm, but not complete when equipped with the $L^2$ norm. My question is how would one find the set of all norms such that that $X$ is complete? 
From this question ([Complete Inequivalent Norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925533/complete-inequivalent-norms) ) we know the cardinality of this set - but is there no way to describe this set?

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to describe this set?  It is huge and complicated and not a particularly useful set.

Comment: I was just curious about the set.